# write prepared statements in mysql in stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

When I'm calling the below SP I'm getting below error in MySQL workbench:

> Error code 1064: You have an error in MySQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySql server version for the right syntax to use near test_28_05_2018 at line 1;

could someone help in writing the correct StoredProc?

```
call execSql(concat('test_',(select DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%d_%m_%Y'))));

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE execSql (IN sqlq VARCHAR(5000)) 
BEGIN
  SET @sqlv=sqlq;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlv;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to accomplish?  (Also, that date format makes me sad.)

Comment: I am trying to rename the table name in SP and I read somewhere we can do it using a prepared statement. Below is the SP :         
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_name`()
BEGIN
DECLARE student_table varchar(60);

SET @currentDate = (select DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%d_%m_%Y') from DUAL);

SET @student_table=concat('student_table',@currentDate);

CREATE TABLE student_new like student;

ALTER TABLE student RENAME TO student_table;
ALTER TABLE student_new RENAME TO student;

END//
DELIMITER ;

Comment: I don't deal in stored procedures, so forgive me if I'm off track here, but it looks to me as if your procedure `execSql()` executes whatever statement is sent to it.  The statement you're sending it, `test_<sad_date>`, is not a valid SQL statement.  Thus the error.  The procedure in your comment looks more like something that might create a table!  Perhaps try that instead?